# OR-ing qualifications with MTurk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, mechanicalturk

Is it possible to have a user have one of multiple Qualifications in order to work on a HIT. For example:

```
qualifications = Qualifications()
qualifications.add(
    Requirement(comparator='EqualTo', integer_value=6, qualification_type_id=NewTest)
)
qualifications.add(
    Requirement(comparator='EqualTo', integer_value=6, qualification_type_id=OldTest)
)
```

The user would need to have one of the `NewTest` or `OldTest` qualification. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All QualificationRequirements follow an AND logic: a worker must satisfy all of them to be able to work on the HIT. You can, however, have an OR logic on the value of a single QualificationRequirement using the "In" comparator. So, if you combine your qualifications into one, use `comparator = "In"` and then specify a comma-separated list of values, a worker who has any one of those values will be allowed to do the HIT.

Comment: How would you complete your own HIT to test with then? For example, Assignments approved > 100 (but I have zero). I don't mean testing in the sandbox environment by removing the Qualifications, but actually testing the 'real' HITs.

Comment: @David542 There's no way to fake your qualifications. I think this is a serious limitation of the sandbox, but it's not something AWS has ever mentioned trying to work on. Your only option is to remove the qualification(s) and test it without them. I've never heard of qualifications causing a problem for a HIT to not work.